# There is a broken Sophos entry in Keychain Access after uninstalling the program - how do I remove it?

Tags: keychain, plist, macos, anti-virus

I've followed [the official instructions](https://community.sophos.com/kb/pl-pl/122638) and also tried running [the official removal tool](https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/121206) (which btw hangs) for Sophos anti-virus for Mac but I still see a "Sophos" entry in Keychain Access.

I have also see errors in Console when system services try to open `/Library/Sophos Anti-Virus/Sophos.keychain` which is a non-existant file. I've even tried recreating a file in that path followed by `sudo security delete-keychain "/Library/Sophos Anti-Virus/Sophos.keychain"` but the entry still remains in the list of keychains.

How can I remove this annoying Sophos leftover?

(can't remember which Sophos edition I originally installed, maybe it was called "Home", maybe that is the only one for Mac)

Answer (score 3):

To fix this you have to manually edit the file `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security-common.plist`, as root, and delete the corresponding hardcoded `<dict>...Sophos...</dict>` entry in there.

**Great care** must be taken because you can totally screw up  your system(-keychain) if you leave any errors inside this .plist file. The section that needs to be deleted looks as follows:

```
...
<dict>
    <key>DbName</key>
    <string>/Library/Sophos Anti-Virus/Sophos.keychain</string>
    <key>GUID</key>
    <string>{some UUID string here}</string>
    <key>SubserviceType</key>
    <integer>6</integer>
</dict>
...
```

Upon save, there should no longer be any "Sophos" entry in Keychain Access or as output of `security list-keychains`.

I used `vim` and deleted the offending lines as (`sudo vim /Library/Preferences/com.apple.security-common.plist`) but you may use any text or plist editor you like - I frankly don't know with one is the most accessible (recommendations welcome).