# How can I remove a keychain that won't delete?

Tags: security, keychain

I have a rogue keychain called Sophos.keychain. I uninstalled Sophos, but this pesky keychain won't go away. The reason I need it removed is Adobe's apps are trying to use it and it is causing errors.

When I log in as root, I see the keychain in the Keychain Access app, but I cannot delete it. There is a small icon on the keychain file icon that looks like a user icon (maybe).

When I am logged in as my normal admin account, I cannot see this Sophos keychain file.

As root, I have also tried deleting it via command line using `security list-keychains` and then `security delete-keychain` with the path to the Sophos.keychain file. Nothing seems work.

Sophos will not assist as I was using the free version. Googling how to remove it leads to dead ends. Apple has also been useless.

When I login as root, I get these errors:[image: error messages]

Clicking on Reset to Defaults, and putting in the password doesn't seem to do anything.

I am on Big Sur 11.5.2

Any ideas how I can remove this keychain file?

Comment: Can you rename it?

Comment: @juandesant No, i can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/277766/9314) seemed to contain the key to the answer:

> To fix this you have to manually edit the file `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security-common.plist` as root, and delete the corresponding hardcoded `<dict>...Sophos...</dict>` entry in there.
> Great care must be taken because you can totally screw up  your system(-keychain) if you leave any errors inside this `.plist` file. The section that needs to be deleted looks as follows:
>
> ```
>  ...
>  <dict>
>      <key>DbName</key>
>      <string>/Library/Sophos Anti-Virus/Sophos.keychain</string>
>      <key>GUID</key>
>      <string>{some UUID string here}</string>
>      <key>SubserviceType</key>
>      <integer>6</integer>
>  </dict>
>  ...
> ```

However, there your setup, as indicate in the comments, was somewhat different, and required finding the right file.

The relevant file path was found to be `/private/var/root/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.plist`

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't see that answer before obviously. I appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, I do not have a `com.apple.security-common.plist` file in `/Library/Preferences` when logged in as root

Comment: I'm afraid logging in as root is something not really supported by macOS — and you actually need to work to enable it. Having said that, I do not have a `com.apple.security-common.plist` either, so maybe that has changed in newer versions of macOS. What is the output of running `security list-keychains -d root` while logged in as root?

Comment: Or do you just mean something like doing `sudo bash` or `sudo zsh`, @Colin ?

Comment: One more question: what are the results of this command: `plutil -p ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security*.plist | grep -i sophos`

Comment: I have enabled the root user. Below is a screen capture of the output of those commands. Unfortunately, I couldn't save a file in TextEdit and the commands for outputting the terminal content to a file were not clear to me. Also, the first command you gave me didn't work, so I replaced root with user.

https://share.getcloudapp.com/JruxoOqn

Comment: OK, I think we are on the right track; could you please show the output of `find /Library/Preferences/ -name "com.apple.security*.plist"`? The last result showed that you have indeed two preference files that link to the Sophos keychain. We need to get their names so that we can use the technique above to remove them, but using those files instead.

Comment: Here is the output of that command:
https://share.getcloudapp.com/DOuBrD5N

I see there is a double slash after the /Preferences/ folder? That seems odd.

Comment: Don’t worry about the double slash: that is a consequence of the command being `find /Library/Preferences/` instead of `find /Library/Preferences`.

Comment: Can you try to apply the solution in the [previously linked question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/277766/9314), but on the files that you found with the previous command? https://share.getcloudapp.com/DOuBrD5N

Comment: I found the file finally. For some reason, it didn't occur to me that Apple would also hide the Library folder in root user folder. Anyway, I have the file to edit. One more question – there are 2 instances of 
`<string>/Library/Sophos Anti-Virus/Sophos.keychain</string>`
in the file. One is in an array with a key of `DLDBSearchList` and the other is in an array with key of `DefaultKeychain` (the default array only has the Sophos keychain in it). Do I delete both of these? Or will deleting the default one mess up the OS?

Comment: Great to hear that you found the file, @Colin, could you please share what is the path to the file (abstracting `/Users/your.username/` to `~/` for privacy)?

Comment: Also, regarding your questions, what I would do is a) remove the DLDBSearchList entry; b) change the entry in `DefaultKeychain` to the output of `security list-keychains -d user` that ends in `login.keychain-db`. BTW, if you run `security list-keychains -d user` as a different user, did you get the Sophos keychain as well?

Comment: BTW, I will change this answer to the exact process that you went through after it is finished, and I'd appreciate if you upvoted it ;-)

Comment: The path to the file is `/private/var/root/Library/Preferences/ `
The file that I edited is `com.apple.security.plist` (I was logged in as root to see this and edit)
When I ran the `security list-keychains` in my normal admin account, the Sophos keychain was not listed. It was only listed when logged in as admin. And yes, I will definitely upvote and mark yours as the answer! You have been a lifesaver. I sincerely appreciate you sticking with me until this was solved!

Comment: Why was `su` not sufficient in this case?

Answer (score 1):

[I would just comment, but I don't have enough reputation points.]
You didn't say which version of macOS you're using, or if you actually got an error message when trying to delete the keychain from within the Keychain Access utility.  Years ago, I created a private keychain file to keep all my secure notes separate from my login.keychain (and a different password is required to open it).  That resulted in a file called <private keychain name>.keychain being created in the ~/Library/Keychains folder.  That file is still there to this day, and gets updated every time I modify the private keychain.  Nowadays, there is also a <private keychain name>.keychain-db file in the same directory.  Try to find your Sophos.keychain file(s) in a similar location on your system, and delete it/them using Finder or Terminal (perhaps make compressed copies in case you need to recover).  Please note, I have not tried this myself...  [On reading @juandesant's answer, I defer to his suggestion.]

Comment: Sorry, I should have included the OS version, etc. I fleshed out my question with some more details. When I use security list-keychains, I do see the Sophos.keychain with the path, but when I go to that path, it is not there.